# How to ask for data in DATETIME formated column

Tags: php, datetime, sqlite

I have a raspberry pi 3 with **apache2 / sqlite3 / php5.5** installed.
Database is created *dbname.db* and inside the table *temps* there are two columns.

- The first column store tempratures named temp.
- The second column    store date and time in (DATETIME) format as
  (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)    named timestamp.

In my php file i have

```
<?php
        ..
        //get all data from temps
        $result1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM temps");
        //get last 1 day data from temps
        $result2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM temps WHERE timestamp >= datetime('now','-1 day')");
        ...    
    ?>
```

1. I need a query to return tempratures from the past **#** days where
   user can select the number **#**. For example if user select 9, i
   need the tempratures for the last 9 days.
2. Also how i can do the same thing with time? for example lets say i
   need tempratures between (00:00:00 and 13:00:00).
3. And last how i can combine date and time together.For example i lets say i need the tempratures between (00:00:00 and 13:00:00) for (2017-03-01)

Answer (score -1):

Use `AND` – maybe using `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM `temps`
WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN NOW() AND INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND TIME(`timestamp`) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '13:00:00'
```